# Frozen gui after google-chrome maximize

Tags: google-chrome, gui

From time to time happens to me, when i move google-chrome window to the top of the screen to maximize it, suddenly the gui freezes with the window showing as maximizing with orange borders and shade. Mouse also doesn't work. I'm using ubuntu 13.10. Is there some way to avoid this behavior or to get back to working gui with all opened programs?
I have tried going to ctrl+alt+f1 and killing google-chrome which brings me back to login screen.

Comment: I've had a lot of problems with chrome, try using chromium inplace of chrome: `sudo aptitude install chromium`

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to keep using firefox as it works perfectly, Chromium is not Google Chrome and although it is not branded by google it has the same exact source code as Google Chrome so it won't be helpful.

PS: if you want a stable webkit browser (same as Google Chrome and Apple Safari) for Linux I would go for:

http://midori-browser.org/download/ubuntu/